# Not showing correctly icon in MasterDetailPage Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building cross platfomr app in Xamarin Forms but iOS not showing MasterDetailPage icon correctly.

How to solve this.

iOS:

[image]

Android:

[image]

Some idea for iOS to show like Android?

Comment: Is that MasterDetailPage? If so, you need to put an image into ios folder and set it as the icon of the page.

Comment: Yes i have this. Some idea?

Answer (score 2):

If using the app logo icon:

[image]

it will show as follows:

[image]

Because the background color of the icon is not Transparent. If the background color of icon is transparent, it will work.

Such as `contacts.png`:

[image]

The effect:

[image]

Or other `Xamarin-50.png`:

[image]

The effect:

[image]

================================Update================================

If you want to show the original color of icon, you need to use the image from **Asset Catalogs**, you can refer to [Adding images to an asset catalog image set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=windows#adding-images-to-an-asset-catalog-image-set) to add icon inside asset, but not forget to set icon **Render as Original**.

For example, image named **Cat** and add source image as follows:

[image]

Then move to the properties of **Cat** and  **Render as Original**:

[image]

The effect:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! but dont working :(
I edited my question

Comment: @AlfredoLopez I have checked your updated question. If you want to show the original color of icon, you need to use Asset Catalogs to show image. I have updated my answer, you could have a check. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: @AlfredoLopez Glad it works! Thanks for marking.

Comment: @AlfredoLopez Hi, have you solved it? If there are other problems, you could create a new question in SO.